# Does Mordecai keep helping you after the quests?

Tags: borderlands-2

I find it kind of hard to slag some enemies, and right now the badass rank is leveling up more on the slag damage that Mordecai inflicts.

So, my question is, if after I finish the quest of the Train in Tundra he keeps helping with this damage.

Comment: no, he go somewhere else until you meet him in Wildlife Preserve.

Comment: :( well, I guess I'm gonna have to follow up with the damage somewhere else then.

Ok.

Thank you!

Comment: @NamikazeSheena - you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

After completing the history quest he won't be avaiable to help with slagging enemies. It will only occur again in a small part of the Wildlife Exploitation Preserve.

But if you so desire to do another quest without completing the history one, he will keep helping you anyway on that map.

Comment: A small note: Slagging is easier with sniper rifles. Sniper Rifles most of the time have more than 30% of elemental chance, that can be increased even further with Badass Ranks and with the passive skill of the Siren.

Comment: That's probably because sniper rifles with slag tend to be manufactured by Maliwan, which always have a higher element chance/damage than other weapons.

Comment: i always use Grog Nozzle for slagging, it`s handgun (so faster shot), have "Drunk" effect, and it can heal you too :D

Comment: I usually have an SMG for slagging. They don't have as high of a chance, but Maliwan ones are pretty high, and they shoot more, so you get more opportunities for it to work.